# What's char* const argv[]?

Tags: c++, pointers, char, constants, exec

I'm studying linux C++ programing when I see

```
int execve(const char *path,
           char *const argv[],
           char *const envp[]);
```

I don't understand what is `char *const argv[]` . I know `char *const foo` is a const pointer to char. And `const char *foo` is a pointer to a const char. But what's `char *const argv[]`?

Is it an array of const pointers to char or an array of pointers to const char?

And I have a `vector<string>` now, how to convert it to `char *const argv[]`?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

> Is it an array of const pointers to char or an array of pointers to const char?

Read types right to left:
const always binds to the left (unless it is on the very left)

```
char *const argv[]

                ^^ Array of
      ^^^^^        const
     ^             pointer to
^^^^               char
```

An array of `"const pointer"` to char

So the pointers in the array can not be modified.
But what they point at can be modified.

Note: As pointed out by Steve below. Because this is being used as a parameter. It actually decays to a "A pointer to `"const pointer"` to char" or "char* const *".

> And I have a vector<string> now, how to convert it to char *const argv[]?

```
int execve(const char *path,
       char *const argv[],
       char *const envp[]);

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string>   data;  /// fill
    std::vector<char*>         argv;
    std::vector<char*>         envp;

    for(std::vector<std::string>::iterator loop = data.begin(); loop != data.end(); ++loop)
    {
        argv.push_back(&(*loop)[0]);
    }

    // I also bet that argv and envp need to be NULL terminated
    argv.push_back(NULL);
    envp.push_back(NULL);
    execve("MyAppName", &argv[0], &envp[0]);
}
```

Comment: It's true that `char *const argv[]` is an array type, but in this context, a function parameter, the type is not `char *const argv[]`, it is `char *const *argv`.

Answer (score 4):

[cdecl.org](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=char%20*const%20argv%5B%5D) says:

> ```
> char *const argv[]
> ```
>
> declare `argv` as array of `const` pointer to `char`

Comment: and how to convert `vector<string>` to `char *const argv[]`?

Comment: @MrPhone: Maybe post that as a separate question. It's simple enough, but it takes more than a comment to write out.

Answer (score 2):

```
// says: argv is a constant pointer pointing to a char*
int main(int c, char *const argv[]);
```

**You won't be able to change "argv" within the function.**

As you are just learning C, i recommend you to really try to understand the differences between arrays and pointers first instead of the common things.

In the area of parameters and arrays, there are a few confusing rules that should be clear before going on. First, what you declare in a parameter list is treated special. There are such situations where things don't make sense as a function parameter in C. These are

- Functions as parameters
- Arrays as parameters

**Arrays as parameters**

The second maybe is not immediately clear. But it becomes clear when you consider that the size of an array dimension is part of the type in C (and an array whose dimension size isn't given has an incomplete type). So, if you would create a function that takes an array by-value (receives a copy), then it could do so only for one size! In addition, arrays can become large, and C tries to be as fast as possible.

In C, for these reasons, array-values are not existent. If you want to get the value of an array, what you get instead is a pointer to the first element of that array. And herein actually already lies the solution. Instead of drawing an array parameter invalid up-front, a C compiler will transform the type of the respective parameter to be a pointer. Remember this, it's very important. The parameter won't be an array, but instead it will be a pointer to the respective element type.

Now, if you try to pass an array, what is passed instead is a pointer to the arrays' first element.

**Excursion: Functions as parameters**

For completion, and because i think this will help you better understand the matter, let's look what the state of affairs is when you try to have a function as a parameter. Indeed, first it won't make any sense. How can a parameter be a function? Huh, we want a variable at that place, of course! So what the compiler does when that happens is, again, to transform the function into a function pointer. Trying to pass a function will pass a pointer to that respective function instead. So, the following are the same (analogous to the array example):

```
void f(void g(void));
void f(void (*g)(void));
```

Note that parentheses around `*g` is needed. Otherwise, it would specify a function returning `void*`, instead of a pointer to a function returning `void`.

**Back to arrays**

Now, i said at the beginning that arrays can have an incomplete type - which happens if you don't give a size yet. Since we already figured that an array parameter is not existent but instead any array parameter is a pointer, the array's size doesn't matter. That means, the compiler will translate all of the following, and all are the same thing:

```
int main(int c, char **argv);
int main(int c, char *argv[]);
int main(int c, char *argv[1]);
int main(int c, char *argv[42]);
```

Of course, it doesn't make much sense to be able to put any size in it, and it's just thrown away. For that reason, C99 came up with a new meaning for those numbers, and allows other things to appear between the brackets:

```
// says: argv is a non-null pointer pointing to at least 5 char*'s
// allows CPU to pre-load some memory. 
int main(int c, char *argv[static 5]);

// says: argv is a constant pointer pointing to a char*
int main(int c, char *argv[const]);

// says the same as the previous one
int main(int c, char ** const argv);
```

The last two lines say that you won't be able to change "argv" within the function - it has become a `const` pointer. Only few C compilers support those C99 features though. But these features make it clear that the "array" isn't actually one. It's a pointer.

**A word of Warning**

Note that all i said above is true only when you have got an array as a parameter of a function. If you work with local arrays, an array won't be a pointer. It will behave as a pointer, because as explained earlier an array will be converted to a pointer when its value is read. But it should not be confused with pointers.

One classic example is the following:

```
char c[10]; 
char **c = &c; // does not work.

typedef char array[10];
array *pc = &c; // *does* work.

// same without typedef. Parens needed, because [...] has 
// higher precedence than '*'. Analogous to the function example above.
char (*array)[10] = &c;
```